# How to do a  Automatic shutdown when Dropbox stops synching?

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, dropbox

Is it possible, or rather is there a way to automatically shutdown Ubuntu (I'm running 12.04) when Dropbox stops synching? That would really suit my needs and cut power consumption.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script that runs every 30 seconds (after being manually invoked by the user), and checks the output of the command `dropbox status`. If the status is found to be `Idle` for 3-4 consecutive runs, I would then issue the command for shutdown.

Comment: Thanks Marios Zindillis, but I don't know how to do that. Any instructions? Please.